# How to get the class probabilities during the evaluation of CIFAR-10 in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I try to modify the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py) from the [Convolutional Neural Network TensorFlow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn) to get the single probabilities for each class from each test-images.

What alternative to [`tf.nn.in_top_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/in_top_k) can I use? Because this method returns only one boolean tensor. But I want to preserve the individual values.

I use Tensorflow 1.4 and Python 3.5, I think lines 62-82 and 121-129 / 142 are probably the lines to be modified. Somebody have a hint for me?

Lines 62-82:

```
def eval_once(saver, summary_writer, top_k_op, summary_op):
  """Run Eval once.
  Args:
    saver: Saver.
    summary_writer: Summary writer.
    top_k_op: Top K op.
    summary_op: Summary op.
  """
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
      # Restores from checkpoint
      saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
      # Assuming model_checkpoint_path looks something like:
      #   /my-favorite-path/cifar10_train/model.ckpt-0,
      # extract global_step from it.
      global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
    else:
      print('No checkpoint file found')
return
```

Lines 121-129 + 142

```
    [....]
    images, labels = cifar10.inputs(eval_data=eval_data)

    # Build a Graph that computes the logits predictions from the
    # inference model.
    logits = cifar10.inference(images)

    # Calculate predictions.
    top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)
    [....]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the class probabilities from the raw `logits`:

```py
# The vector of probabilities per each example in a batch
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

As a bonus, here's how to get the exact accuracy:

```py
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, when i have to call tf.nn.softmax(logits) ?

Comment: yes, but who get it calculate? sess.run(prediction) doesn't work.

Comment: Did you start a new session or passed it to `eval_once`?